# SqlConnection.ChangePassword new password does not work immediately

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I inherited a web application that has uses individual SQL account for authentication.  I need to update the login procedure to use a different type of hash.

Pseudo code

```
if (login(newhash(password)) == 0) // login using new hash function doesn't work
{
    if (login(oldhash(password)) == 1) // login with old hash works
    {
        SqlConnection.ChangePassword(connstr);
        login(newhash(password)); 
    }
}
```

The problem is the second login(newhash(password) would not immediately work.  If I put a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) in between the ChangePassword and the login then it would work.  SqlConnection is closed properly when doing the login()

I also tried using sp_password instead, but it still won't authenticate immediately with the new password.  Is there any way to eliminate this "password change lag"?

EDIT:

I added SqlConnection.ClearPool(conn) and the problem persist. SQL Profiler showed the following:

1. Audit Login Failed
2. Audit Login
3. SQL:BatchStarting
4. SQLBatchCompleted
5. Audit Login Change Password Event
6. Audit Login
7. Audit Login Failed

So everything is expected from 1-6, however I don't know where does #7 come from.

Comment: Does your code compiles? cause changepassword() doesn't takes a single argument.

Comment: Maybe an open transaction which is only committed after a while?

Comment: My code does compile.  The password is changed successfully if I wait about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a connection in the connection pool that is getting in your way, [How Can I Prevent Recurring Automatic Connections to Oracle Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877042/how-can-i-prevent-recurring-automatic-connections-to-oracle-database) . Try clearing the pool before trying to reauthenticate, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool(v=vs.110).aspx .